# OpenCV on iOS - VideoCapture properties always return 1

Tags: ios, opencv

I have been trying to build a simple OpenCV (iOS) app that loads a video from the bundle and queries it for its frame count, duration, etc. then it will try to grab individual frames from it. Unfortunately, when I use `VideoCapture` class, all the properties return values of 1. Then I try to navigate to `frame #100` but that also doesn't work. Am I doing this the wrong way?

```
cv::VideoCapture capture([[movieURL path] UTF8String]);
if (!capture.isOpened()) {
    Log(@"Could not open the video:%@", [movieURL path]);
}

double rate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

cv::Mat frame; //current video frame

//Delay between each frame in ms
//corresponds to video frame rate
int delay = 1000/rate;

long numOfFrames = static_cast<long>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));

Log(@"Video Frame rate:%f, delay:%d, numOfFrames:%ld", rate, delay, numOfFrames);

double position = 100.0;
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, position);

long frameNum = static_cast<long>(capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC));

Log(@"Moved to Frame 100. Getting frame number:%ld", frameNum);
```

Comment: This is probably trivial for some, but I'm an absolute beginner in working with OpenCV so I would appreciate help. Please note that I also tested recording using CvVideoCamera and wrote it to a file using CvVideoWriter then tested it and still got the same results. I was thinking that maybe because the video was recorded by other than OpenCV classes that it was causing the problem, but apparently it's different :(

Comment: A couple of more things that I'm discovering: if I set the file extension to .mp4/mov then I get 1's but if I set it to .avi then I get 0's.

Comment: Hi--- have you been able to figure this out? I'm getting the same results as you.  I hope you've had some luck with this..

Comment: @RVC  did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yet another year later, and all iOS OpenCV properties return 1 for .mov files…
@RVC: did you ever find a fix?